# What's the proper form of "As a judge of your parents actions"?

Tags: academic-writing, punctuation, grammar

A grammar checker is saying I have two options, but which one is proper since you have two parents:

- parents'
- parent's

Note: this is for a Theology Masters paper that I hope to eventually publish into a book.

Comment: possibly better suited to english language and usage SE.

Comment: It's still a writing question on grammar.

Comment: Yeah, but the point of ELU SE is for grammar, you could make the point that everything in ELU SE is writing and should be here, but that's not how it works. There is a grammar tag in writing SE but it should be used for grammar in a sentence or paragraph with provided context.

Comment: "since you have two parents" - um, no, not everyone. So where you put the apostrophe defines whether you mean one parent or multiple parents.

Comment: it takes a village of non-fools to raise good kids

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Parents'* is the plural.  *Parent's* is the singular.

Answer (score 0):

The first one (parents') is correct.

**Parent's** shows that something belongs to *one* parent.

**Parents'** shows that something belongs to *both* parents.